# why Multi select control losing style after postback?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap, listbox

I am using Listbox with Jquery method to add style to it as shown

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
     $(window).load(function () {
         $('[id*=ckStores]').multiselect({
             includeSelectAllOption: true
         });
     });
    </script>
 <asp:ListBox ID="ckStores" runat="server"   CssClass ="multiselect-group"    SelectionMode="Multiple"   >

      </asp:ListBox>
```

when page post back Listbox contol lost style and back to default bootstrab style .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to Load the multi-select code in the following way :

```
$(document).ready(function () {

           Sys.Application.add_load(function () {

              $('[id*=ckStores]').multiselect({
         includeSelectAllOption: true
     });

           });

       });
```